# Seeding a hiberate ORM database in Spring Boot

Tags: database, hibernate

I am new to Spring Boot and hiberate ROM and was wondering how do you typically seed your database? What is the standard way of inserting data into the db for development?

For example in asp.net I see alot of projects create 'seed' classes which insert data upon the creation of a database.

Comment: A SQL script, a database dump, a liquibase/flyway changeset activated for a dev profile...

Comment: It sounds like a flywheel would be the way to go as it's db agnostic and is well supported